# Striking a balance between typeahead-wait-ms and number of requests fired off (angular ui typeahead)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, typeahead

I am using [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for a typeahead, and I've got a bit of a problem. Specifically, I am looking at this variable

```
typeahead-wait-ms $ (Default: 0) - Minimal wait time after last character typed before typeahead kicks-in.
```

I've found that by using this variable, and setting it to 300 ms or so, I've drastically reduced the number of requests to my backend. This is a good thing.

However, I now need to wait for my returned data structure before the text in the text bar updates.

It goes a little something like this.

The term with the "X" to the left is what is highlighted by default.

```
1)
[foo]              <----- current text in text bar
    -X[foo]        <----- original text {"text" : "foo"}
    - [match 1]     <----- match 1 {"text" : "match1"}
    - [match 2]     <----- match 2 {"text" : "match2"}

2)
[foo bar]          <----- updated text in text bar
    -X[foo]        <----- note that the typeahead contents have not yet updated
    - [match 1]     <----- at this point we are fetching matches for "foo bar" from the backend
    - [match 2]    

3)
[foo bar]              <----- updated text in text bar
    -X[foo bar]        <----- after the 300ms, the typeahead contents updates
    - [match 3]    
    - [match 4]
```

My problem is.... when I click the enter key between step 2 and 3, the content has not returned from the backend... so instead of

```
function select($item, $model, $label) {
    //$item.text = "foo bar"
```

which is the term that is in the text bar, I get

```
function select($item, $model, $label) {
    //$item.text = "foo"
```

which was the last "highlighted term" before the contents updated.

I tried to compare the ng-model variable... something like this

```
// typeahead html
ng-model= "term"
typeahead-on-select="select"

// bound function
function select($item, $model, $label) {
    alert($scope.term);
}
```

And then $scope.term comes up undefined.

Now, when I completely remove the typeahead-wait-min, the requests fire off faster than I can hit enter. So that is ok... but I don't want to be making a request for every character the user types in.

Just spitballing solutions... is there a way to immediately put the original search term in the results, and then fill the rest of the results in when they are prepared?